# Nested AJAX request in Javascript/jQuery, it's a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code:

```
if ($fabricante.length > 0) {
    var fabricante = $fabricante.val();
    $fabricante.select2({
        ajax: {
            ...
        },
        formatAjaxError: function () {
            ...
        }
    }).change(function () {
        $.get(Routing.generate('obtenerFabricanteProductoSolicitud'), {id: $id}, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.success === true) {
                ...
                $('.editable-pais').on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.get(Routing.generate('obtenerPaisesFabricantes'), {fabricante_distribuidor_id: data.ent.id, producto_solicitud_id: data.ent.idProductoSolicitud}, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        ....
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Because the nature of the code and because I update the DOM with new element on the first `$.get()` Ajax call then I need a second Ajax call on `.done()` callback of the first one `$.get()`, is that a good practice or not? I'm running this doubt for a while and need some advice from someone than Google results

**Test #1:**

So I'm testing my own code with nested Ajax calls and I'm running the problem issued by @art-mcbain as the image below shows:

[image]

A brief explanation, three rows with three button at last TD, trigger click on first button (+ image) will return three calls for subsequent `.editable-pais`, trigger click event on the second one will produce two calls for subsequent `.editable-pais` and so on and I think if I have twenty rows and do a click event on the first one then I'll have 20 calls and that's insane. So, if the nested Ajax call, depends on the previous one and elements are added on the DOM dynamically, how do I prevent this behavior? This is how the code for each row looks like (example for the first one in the image above):

```
<tr data-id="1" data-idproductosolicitud="18">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="18" name="fabLinkChoice[]"></td>
    <td>Dist1</td>
    <td>DDDDD</td>
    <td class="has_pais fabTd-18"></td>
    <td>1111111</td>
    <td><a data-backdrop="static" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-toggle="modal" data-iteration="0" data-id="18" data-idpais="1" class="editable-pais" href="javascript:void(0)"><i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-original-title="Agregar países"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

Any advice? Workaround? Possible solution?

Comment: If you need the data of the first Ajax call for the second one you don't have any other option.

Comment: As long as it's just a few calls, and it's not really callback hell, doing it that way is fine. If it develops into a nested nightmare, it's probably time to learn how promises work.

Comment: @Vohuman yes I need it on the second call so there is no other way to go as you said

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: The dangers you might run in to issues with longer page responsiveness times, so you'll have to pay close attention to that. Otherwise, unless you can somehow combine the two calls in to one (which itself may not be good practice anyways), then this might appear to be the only way.

Comment: @adeneo yep, I'll not have too nested calls just this two for now and perhaps another one, but is good to know I'm not so lost

Comment: You can use named functions instead of anonymous functions to keep the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting isn't necessarily bad, however an issue here is that if the code above is called more than once over any elements with the class `editable-pais` that existed the last time the code was called you will end up with more than one click handler. This will generate multiple requests to your inner request's URL.

If you don't need data from the first call to complete this call, or the data can be obtained by other means, you may want to consider un-nesting them. jQuery offers the ability to do delegated callbacks if you need to capture events from elements that may not exist yet:

```
$("selector for parent element").on("click", ".editable-pais", function (event) { ... });
```

Comment: Hi @art-mcbain can you take a look to the edit I made on the main post after running some test on my side?

Comment: I don't understand, exactly. My point was multiple calls to that code would add another listener to an element that already had one. The edited question indicates that clicking the first one fires 3 requests, clicking the second 2, etc. That's not quite what I indicated above, unless you clicked them in reverse order (last to first). You may want to kick this out to another top-level Question as it is a different problem than the original Question asked here.